# How to create search view for movie database that can find movie based on title, and tittle + year in search

Tags: python, django, database, search

I am looking to create a search class that can find the movie when the title has been input into my form, but also want it to find said movie when the title and year is input into form as well.

This is the view.py I have atm which will find movie based on title, but once I add the year on the end, it will not find it.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from .models import Movie
from django.db.models import Q

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'movies/front_page.html'

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'movies/search_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'search_all_movies'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return Movie.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)
```

UPDATE - I have coded this but still not working?

```
'''
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        title = ''.join(query.split(' ')[-1:])
        year = ''.join(query.split(' ')[-1])
        if year.startswith('19') | year.startswith('20'):
            return Movie.objects.filter(title__icontains=title)
        else:
            return Movie.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
'''
```

UPDATE -

```
'''
title = ''.join(query.split(' ')[-1:])
'''
```

is wrong. I had to change [-1:] to [:-1] and it works fine now. For anyone that is interested of comes accross this post. Thanks everyone.

Comment: It is logical that it will not find it and also the part of your code is not much of a help. But if you want in one input to search 2 fields you should split your search string and search in both fields independently

Comment: Yea but If I do that, I don't want all movies form a specif year to be showing up, that I why I need to search for "title" AND "title + year". Basically.

Comment: That depends on your query. You can select `Movie.objects.exclude(Q(title__contains="the_title") & ~Q(year__contains="the_year"))`

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I think if I could even just let the search find the movie title and ignore the year on the end, that would be fine also... it is just that when I search say "venom" I get a result, when I search "venom 2018" I do not... in my models, the year is a CharField btw also.

Comment: You can't get results if you search for "venom 2018" because the title would be "venom" and with year provided you would get something that does not exist. In that case you should split your string i.e. "venom 2018".split(' ')[0] to get only the name but that is a specific example it does not apply for all searches!

Comment: Yes i know, this is what i have been trying to do, I have come up with something but for some reason still not working? I updated and put code above. Thanks

Comment: Got it working! The code above on title I had the [-1:] wrong way round it should be [:-1]. Thanks for the help anyway :)